# find $\lim_{x \to {0^-}}(e^{1/x})\cos x$ without using l'Hopital's rule

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I would separate this limit but $1/x$ is an indeterminate form, which is where I'm stuck.

Comment: For this problem I think you could use the squeeze theorem to find your result.

Answer (score 3):

$\cos(x) \to 1$
and
$\lim_{x \to 0^{-}} e^{1/x}
= 0$
so the limit is their product
or $0$.

Comment: Why is $e^(1/x) =0$?

Comment: As $x \to -0$, $1/x \to -\infty$ so $e^{1/x} \to e^{-\infty} = 1/e^{\infty} = 0$. I'm really talking about limits here, so don't get upset at $e^{\infty}$.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Try subbing in $u = 1/x$. After doing this, the limit now goes to $-\infty$.

$\lim e^u\cos(1/u)$

Then, we can use squeeze theorem:

$-1 < \cos(1/u) < 1$

$-e^u < e^u\cos(1/u) < e^u$

Remember that $e^u$ approaches $0$ as u goes to $-\infty$. Subbing in $-\infty$ squeezes $e^u\cos(1/u)$ into $0$. The limit $ = 0$